# How can I identify the damping of the modes in a signal by Cmor wavelet method?

Tags: matlab, frequency, wavelet

I read several papers which proposed a method to identify modal parameters. such as natural frequency and damping ratio.I've tried to implement those methods by Matlab.but I couldn't get the result.It seems I missed something.anyway it must be some problem with my codes.Please check it and see what's the problem. [here you can access to the paper which I've tried to implement its method](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5708194).
here you can see the brief relationships to identify damping and frequency.
[image]
and here is the code. please look and see if I am doing these relationships right or not.also if you have another method to extract the damping of a mode,please do tell me.
Best regards.

```
t=linspace(0,30,300);
Fs=ceil(inv(t(2)-t(1)));                               % sampling freq
x=sin(2*pi*t*0.1).*(t<10)+sin(2*pi*t*0.3).*... 
 (t<30)+sin(2*pi*t*0.6).*(t<10).*exp(-t*.1);           % my signal[0.1Hz,0.3Hz,0.6Hz]
wname = 'cmor20-1';                                    % define wavelet name
scales = 1:1:256;                                     % scales range
freq = scal2frq(scales,wname,1/Fs);
coefs = cwt(x,scales,wname,'lvlabs');                  % Get coefs of x
abscof=abs(coefs);                                     % |coefs|' 
logcof=log(abscof);                                    % Ln|Wx(a,b)|
argcof=angle(coefs);                                   % arg[Wx(a,b)]
%--calculating linear regression to get alpha & omega--
for j=1:256                                            % for all scales
n=length(t);
aa(j)=-((n*sum(t.*logcof(j,:))-sum(t)*...              % its alpha
sum(logcof(j,:))))/(n*sum(t.^2)-(sum(t))^2);
ba(j)=mean(logcof(j,:))-aa(j)*mean(t);
aw(j)=-((n*sum(t.*argcof(j,:))-sum(t)*...              %its omega
sum(argcof(j,:))))/(n*sum(t.^2)-(sum(t))^2);            
bw(j)=mean(argcof(j,:))-aw(j)*mean(t);
f(j)=aw(j)/(2*pi);
dmp(j)=-aa(j)/sqrt(aa(j).^2+aw(j).^2);
end
%%
% this bit will give me freq of all modes in the signal.but i must get these
%information with f(j) too. however my main problem is getting the damping. 
figure;
modI=max(abscof');                                      % get  max |coefs| coresponde to freqs of x 
modI=modI/max(modI);                                   % scale each clumn 0-1
plot(freq,modI)                                        % Plot all modes. contain all 
grid on
axis([0 3 0 max(modI)*1.1])                            % seting the axis
xlabel('Pseudo-Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('abs(coefs)'); % seting the axis
```

Comment: Any Idea how to get damping with wavelet method? :(

Comment: I am also following the paper you mentioned. Have you solved the problem of finding damping of the signal? Please let me know if u get the solution. Thanks in Advance