# infomation about Stockwell Transform

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, wavelet, s-transform

I need some information about Stockwell transform (also known as the S-transform):

1. How can I implement it in MATLAB?
2. *Does it give you the damping ratio $\zeta$ of a signal like the complex Morlet continuous wavelet? $$x(t)= e^{-\omega_{n}\zeta}\sin(\omega_{d}t+\theta )$$
3. What are its advantages compared to CWT?

The S-transform defined as follows: 
$$s( \tau ,f)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(t) \frac{\ |f|}{\ \sqrt{2 \pi } } e^{ \frac{-(t- \tau )^{2} f^{2}}{2}  }    e^{-j 2 \pi f} dt$$ ([This is a good tutorial about the S-Transform](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http://djj.ee.ntu.edu.tw/S%2520transform.pdf&ei=v-haUuK4J4GEiQLe3YDACw&usg=AFQjCNF60y8azpGczbv1QCDlCmUbriItkg&sig2=aEtFHmLdVPZSFBY-I4BPVA&bvm=bv.53899372,d.cGE))

These are the first few question that I can think about at the moment. It seems no one asked about the S-transform before, so put your questions in this post by editing it, and answer them if you know them. Someone with enough reputation put a tag for S-transform please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This time-frequency representation (not a wavelet) is very similar to the Gabor transform. If you like to implement it, you can start by adapting Gabor's code.

Comment: @Hasan  I used direct cwt function in matlab.so I don't have gabor code in detail. where can I find it?

Comment: http://tftb.nongnu.org/ .

Comment: @Electricman, just FYI, if someone has other questions about S-transforms, they should open new questions and not add them to this question.

Answer (score 4):

The Matlab code of the S-transform can be found here for example: http://en.verysource.com/code/1180181_1/st.m.html

The main advantage compared to CWT is its simplicity. In fact, it can be seen as equivalent to a Morlet wavelet, see for example paper by Ventosa, Schimmel, Simon, Dañobeitia and Mànuel "The S-transform from a wavelet point of view", IEEE Trans on Signal Processing, 2008.

Comment: thanks for the code, here http://en.pudn.com/downloads107/sourcecode/math/detail442126_en.html you can find a better package, It includes inverse Stockwell transform as well. and it works even better. Now I am trying to compare S-T with other similar methods. I will try to post a complete answer when I understand it well. tnx for ur answer

Answer (score 3):

Advantages:

1. The `ST` does the phase of the `TFR`.  For instance, if you have a constant cosine function i.e., $h(t) = Acos(2 \pi f t + \theta),$  then the phase of the `ST` result for that voice `(frequency f)`  is exactly equal to theta for all time.
2. you can get the `FFT` spectrum (the complex values)  by averaging the ST over time.  Which makes a lot of sense to me,  if you have the time varying spectrum you average over time to get the global or FFT spectrum.

Citations:
[Localization of the complex spectrum](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/492555): the S transform
RG Stockwell, L Mansinha, RP Lowe, Signal Processing, IEEE Transactions on 44 (4), 998-1001

[Why use the S-transform Authors](https://bytebucket.org/cleemesser/stockwelltransform/raw/d87ff20d787d36d5280dcd26cbaf309dcd982bf4/ref/Stockwell-Why%20Use%20the%20S-Transform.pdf) RG Stockwell
Publication date 2007 [Journal Pseudo-differential operators: partial differential equations and time-frequency analysis](https://bookstore.ams.org/fic-52)

Comment: Thanks for answer @bob-stockwell . As you know There is are very good approximation for wavelet to extract the damping ratio {check here: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/how-can-i-identify-the-damping-of-the-modes-in-a-signal-by-cmor-wavelet-method , I wrote a complete script for extracting the damping ratio and should answer my earlier question soon}. Would you please explain more how can I extract the damping ratio ($\zeta$) of a namely signal $x(t)= e^{-\omega_{n}\zeta}\sin(\omega_{d}t+\theta )$l with `S-Transform` ?